# How to continue processing when VM instances are stopped?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using streaming word count on dataflow.The flow is "pubsub -> wordcount on dataflow (fixed window) -> pubsub".

When I deploy the pipeline, 3 instances are up.
[https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/matsuda-question/instances.png]

When I publish the text to pubsub, the counted result are publishued to pubsub.
[https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/matsuda-question/input.png]
[https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/matsuda-question/output1.png]

And I manually stop 1 instance of 3 instances. It's like node failure.
[https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/matsuda-question/stopped_instances.png]

The count is not complete. 
[https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/matsuda-question/output2.png]

I guess the node which handles the words "one, two, five" is stopped.
Doesn't dataflow have failover function when some nodes are failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streaming Dataflow does not currently handle stopping instances in the middle of a running job.  However, this is not a possible failure mode in Compute Engine.  It is guaranteed that a failed VM will be restarted again.  If you want to experiment with how your pipeline behaves when nodes fail, you can reset VMs from the developer console.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I got it.